# CBitmap::GetBitmap Failure

Tags: mfc, gdi, cbitmap

What could be the possible reasons of getting return code as 0 from `GetBitmap()`?

```
BITMAP bmInfo;
int rc = bitmap->GetBitmap (&bmInfo);
int ec = GetLastError();
```

The value returned by `GetLastError()` is also 0. MSDN doesn't give any help and all the forums where similar questions have been asked are silent.

To give you some context, I have an instance of CBitmap and I am attaching a second instance of CBitmap to the same HBITMAP using code similar to the following:

```
CBitmap first;
:
:
CBitmap second;
second.Attach ((HBITMAP)first);

BITMAP bmInfo;
second.GetBitmap (&bmInfo);
```

The call to `GetBitmap()` fails for `second` and not for `first`.

Comment: It is unsafe to attach a handle from object that owns it to another to be a new owner. Eventually one of them will be owning an invalid handle.

Comment: @RomanR., this is a valid comment but the above code is a simplified version of what I am trying to do. So, I am taking care of when each object gets destroyed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The call to GetBitmap() fails for second and not for first.

If so, there is no way the two class instances hold the same handle, and your code snippet suggests exactly this. You can break with debugger to check your `first` and `second` to find out what they are actually holding inside.

Comment: Your answer hinted me on the type casting I was done for `HBITMAP`, and that was the culprit. Thanks a lot! I still wonder why `GetLastError()` was returning 0. Shouldn't it give me something like invalid handle on Attach call?

Comment: To guess off the cuff without bothering to look into source code, I'd say your `CBitmap` might be holding `NULL` and GetBitmap would do no API call at all. Hence, `GetLastError` would still hold some successful result from past.